# Resizing of AppWidgetProvider in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I have a class which is dereived from `AppWidgetProvider` . As far as I understand resizing of  widget is android basic method. How can I override it or something, just to add my own implementatation?

Thank you on advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. Resizing, where supported, is handled by the home screen, in conjunction with classes like `AppWidgetHost`.

You are welcome to write your own home screen, of course, and do whatever resizing work you want to do there.